# Plotly Trendline for Line Chart

Tags: python, dataframe, plotly, trendline

Is there any way to easily add a trendline to a plotly express line chart like there is for plotly scatter plot?

I have tried using this line to create my dataframe:

```
fig = px.line(df4, x=df4["DATE"], y=df4['Ratio'], title="Market Ratio", trendline='ols')
```

But it gives the error

```
TypeError: line() got an unexpected keyword argument 'trendline'
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there isn't. And you don't need it. All you need is `px.scatter` and:

```
fig.update_traces(mode = 'lines')
```

This will yield the same result as `px.line` if it *did* have a `trendline` attribute.

[image]

#### Complete code:

```
# imports
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.io as pio

# data
df = px.data.stocks()[['GOOG', 'AAPL']]

# your choices
target = 'GOOG'
colors = px.colors.qualitative.T10

# plotly
fig = px.scatter(df, 
                 x = target,
                 y = [c for c in df.columns if c != target],
                 template = 'plotly_dark',
                 color_discrete_sequence = colors,
                 trendline = 'ols',
                 title = "fig.update_traces(mode = 'lines')")
f = fig.full_figure_for_development(warn=False)
fig.update_traces(mode = 'lines')
fig.data[-1].line.color = 'red'
fig.show()
```